# Hi, I want to edit the copyright text in php wordpress site.

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed wordpress site. i would like to change the copyright content.I cant replace the copyright text. how to find the exact file for change. Please give the details if you know. Also where is placed in the "copyright_text" class.
Please help to replace the text content.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there any theme options or widgets are present in the admin section. Also check your footer.php file present in the theme folder.